# Can this code be simplified for adding a structure to a std::map?

Tags: visual-c++, struct, stdmap

I have this structure:

```
struct S_SWAP_TALK
{
    S_TALK_INFO* pHomeTalk{};
    S_AWAY_TALK* pAwayTalk{};
};
```

And, I have this `std::map`:

```
std::map<UINT, S_SWAP_TALK> m_mapSwapTalks;
```

At the moment, I have populating the map like this:

```
S_SWAP_TALK sSwapTalk{};
sSwapTalk.pAwayTalk = &sAwayTalk;
m_mapSwapTalks[menuItemId] = sSwapTalk;
```

or

```
S_SWAP_TALK sSwapTalk{};
sSwapTalk.pHomeTalk = &sPTI;
m_mapSwapTalks[menuItemId] = sSwapTalk;
```

Is it possible to simplify this code so that I don't need to ddeclare the `S_SWAP_TALK` structure as a variable? Eg:

```
m_mapSwapTalks[menuItemId] = ...;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With C++20 you can write:

```cpp
m_mapSwapTalks[menuItemId] = { .pAwayTalk = &sAwayTalk };
m_mapSwapTalks[menuItemId] = { .pHomeTalk = &sPTI };
```

With earlier versions, you can write:

```cpp
m_mapSwapTalks[menuItemId] = { nullptr, &sAwayTalk };
m_mapSwapTalks[menuItemId] = { &sPTI };
```